# Remove border on only one side for end <li> (Maintain splitting borders)

Tags: html, css

```
#order {
    font-family: HelveticaLTStd-Light;
    font-size:13;
    position: absolute;
    right:218;
    top:-5;
}

    #order ul li {
        float:left;
        padding: 5px;
        border-right: 1px solid;
    }

    <div id="order">
    <ul>
        <li>Order</li>
        <li>Account</li>
        <li>Login</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

i was planning to remove the border next to login and the two on the middle will remain
    but i can't find the answer please help?:)

Order | Account | Login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a class and then assign a no right border to that class. Check it out:

HTML:

```
<div id="order">
<ul>
    <li>Order</li>
    <li>Account</li>
    <li class="noRight">Login</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#order {
    font-family: HelveticaLTStd-Light;
    font-size:13;
    position: absolute;
    right:218;
    top:-5;
}

#order ul li {
    float:left;
    padding: 5px;
    border-right: 1px solid;
}

#order ul li.noRight {
    border-right:0;
}
```

Heres a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qvCCK/) for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pseudo class :first-child to have no borders at all and have the remaining have a left border, effectivly only showing vertical borders inbetween the

elements.

```
   #order ul li:first-child {
    float:left;
    padding: 5px;
    border: none;
}

#order ul li {
    float:left;
    padding: 5px;
    border-left: 1px solid;
}
```

And a fiddle to show

http://jsfiddle.net/AJW2a/

Comment: This is the best solution, `:first-child` works for all browsers while the `:last-child` only works from IE 9+, there is no need to make a extra class.